# Creating and accessing unique html div via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Part of my script using the below to create the div.

days += `<div class="day${i}">${i}</div>`;

My question is how do I access it?

document.querySelector(".day8").addEventListener("click", () => {

Using this method works with other divs I have created but doesn't seem to work with divs inside divs... The structure is "day" inside of "days".

Sorry if this is not clear.

Comment: Hi @Winsmurf, I think you're going to get a lot of comments about how you've structured this question. Do your best to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can be clearer on what you're trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work if the `div` is created after you run the select script(`document.querySelector(".day8").addEventListener("click", () => {`).

The solution is that you will have to run the select script above once again after adding the div.

Comment: Thank you, such a simple mistake. I repositioned the listener to the end of the script... Solved